# Use wininet to read cookies on ASP.NET

Tags: iis, wininet

My ASP.NET application requires a cookies check function. The application will check if a cookies from external site (SharePoint Online site) exists in Internet Explorer.

I followed the `wininet.dll` `InternetGetCookie` method in [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/0c6a0ab4-ac8c-4dfb-8e67-f07118d7d7db), and it works when I run debug mode. But when I deploy the application on `IIS` this method cannot read the cookies anymore, it always return empty cookies.

Does `wininet` work on ASP.NET web application? If so what wrong with get cookie method above? And if not, is there any other solution to read cookies from external site (I've tried `WinHTTP` but it comes with some security warning)?

Answer (score 0):

> Does wininet work on ASP.NET web application?

You don't need to use any `wininet.dll` in order to read cookies. Inside an ASP.NET application you could directly use the [`Request.Cookies`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.cookies.aspx) property to inspect incoming cookies.

For example:

```
protected void Page_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var cookie = Request.Cookies["cookie_name"];
    if (cookie != null)
    {
        string cookieValue = cookie.Value;
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: But `Request.Cookies` only read cookies that you already know its name. My application need to read cookies from external site. So I need a method that accepts an `URL` and check if cookies of this `URL` exists on client machine.

Comment: You cannot read cookies from external sites inside an ASP.NET application simply because they are never sent to your domain. That would be a huge security flaw.

Comment: So why running on debug mode, `InternetGetCookie` can still read the cookies?

Comment: `InternetGetCookie` runs on the client. I guess that when running in Debug mode, you are testing everything on the same computer - the ASP.NET application and the client. But once you deploy your application in IIS and the client computer is entirely different this cannot possibly work.

Comment: Hmmm... So I have to find another approach to check user logged in to SharePoint. Thank you for your response.

Comment: Yes, I am afraid you will have to find another approach.